# How to increment numbers using regex?

Tags: python, string, url

Giving that I have this link `https://website.com/files/2019/08/2/1-screenshot-1-1.png`

And that I want to generate a list of links, with a start and end row, like [1-2] and [3-4]

For example :

```
https://website.com/files/2019/08/2/1-screenshot-1-3.png
https://website.com/files/2019/08/2/1-screenshot-1-4.png
https://website.com/files/2019/08/2/1-screenshot-2-3.png
https://website.com/files/2019/08/2/1-screenshot-2-4.png
```

etc.

How should I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You don't need regex to do this. You can just create a template string, and wherever you want to supply digits, use format specifiers there (e.g. `"https://website.com/files/2019/08/2/1-screenshot-%d-%d.png" % (some_number, some_other_number)`

Comment: I just created a list of numbers / URLs for the first parameter, now I would like to associate the second parameter (2000 numbers for each URL)

For example :
1-screenshot-1
1-screenshot-2
1-screenshot-3
1-screenshot-4
...

2-screenshot-1
2-screenshot-2
2-screenshot-3
2-screenshot-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`regex` is not needed - you could do as follows:

```
my_link = 'https://website.com/files/2019/08/2/1-screenshot-{:d}-{:d}.png'

links = [my_link.format(number1, number2) for number1 in range(1, 3) for number2 in range(1, 3)]

print(links)
```

or

```
links = [f'https://website.com/files/2019/08/2/1-screenshot-{number1}-{number2}.png' for number1 in range(1, 3) for number2 in range(1, 3)]

print(links)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['https://website.com/files/2019/08/2/1-screenshot-1-1.png', 'https://website.com/files/2019/08/2/1-screenshot-1-2.png', 'https://website.com/files/2019/08/2/1-screenshot-2-1.png', 'https://website.com/files/2019/08/2/1-screenshot-2-2.png']
```